# ngx-quill image doesn't render after upload on server

Tags: javascript, angular, quill, ngx-quill

i have tried to implement image upload like in this example for ngx-quill editor: https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ngx-quill/issues/89#issuecomment-542907588

It uploads the image, all is good.
But for some reasons, the image doesn't insert in the editor after server returns me the url to the image.

I notice that

```
range = this.meQuillRef.getSelection(true);
```

range.index it is always 0, i guess it shouldn't be.

Maybe someone already faced this issue and found a solution, thanks!